# return object axis 2 client

Tags: apache-axis

I am new to SOAP and Axis 2 framework. I started with writing simple program for returning String, int to the client side. Now I want to have program on the server which return java Object like Vector, List and Properties to the client side.

But while writing the client side program, I am not able to do that. Please do give some example too in order to understand it easily.

Answer (score 1):

All the released versions of Axis2 does not support List, maps and Vector. So you won't be able to use them. Only solution is to use arrays. Those features are now added to the trunk and will be available for 1.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Der are many ways to do it. You can return objects in the form of JSON, or use JAXB to convert objects into XML and send it. Or u can send plain java objects(But it is not acceptable since they will be soap objects and sometimes may not be receivable by clientside of different platforms). Start with some tutorials for JAXB or Jersey if you want to use Restful architure.